# Copy folder structure and only files name

Tags: linux, file, tree, copy

I want to create a clone of the structure of one big folder (500Gb). I can do this easily with the below command :

> cd /path/to/directories && find . -type d -exec mkdir -p --
>   /path/to/backup/{} \;

Now I also want to clone files (I mean copy each file but empty files)

For example let's suggest /path/to/directories/file.txt takes **1Gb** space.
I want /path/to/backup/file.txt to be *empty* (**1Kb**)

Maybe I can use this command

```
> filename
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

cd /path/to/dirs ; find | while read f ; do [ ! -d "$f" ] && touch "/path/to/backup/$f" || mkdir -p "/path/to/backup/$f" ; done

Regards

Comment: cannot touch /path/to/backup/./anotherFolder  I dont know a dot is inserted

Comment: Have you created the folders at first? I assumed you have, with the method in your question. Please wait a sec, and i extend my answer to cover directory creation either. The dot does not matter at all, because there' a dot entry in every dir, namely the dir itself.

Comment: Is there a space right before the dot? I mean right before $f. There shouldn't be..